# Can I use terebinth instead of Sarsaparilla for root beer?

Tags: root-beer

We do not have sassafrass or sarsaparilla here in Turkey. But we do have terebinth. And I believe they are really similar. Have any of you had any experience on this?

Usually roots of sarsaparilla is commonly used in root beers nowadays. I wonder if anyone had an experiment with terebinth.